# Геолокация средствами Яндекса

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, геолокация

Как сделать что бы вот в этом коде от Яндекса поиск происходил автоматически без нажатия кнопочки. [Код в песочнице.](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.0/geolocation_api)

```
function init () {

    //...

    ymaps.util.augment(GeolocationButton, ymaps.control.Button, {
        /**
         * Метод будет вызван при добавлении кнопки на карту.
         * @function
         * @name GeolocationButton.onAddToMap
         * @param {ymaps.Map} map Карта на которую добавляется кнопка.
         */
        onAddToMap: function () {
            GeolocationButton.superclass.onAddToMap.apply(this, arguments);

            ymaps.option.presetStorage.add('geolocation#icon', {
                iconImageHref: 'man.png',
                iconImageSize: [27, 26],
                iconImageOffset: [-10, -24]
            });

            this.hint = new GeolocationButtonHint(this);
            // Обрабатываем клик на кнопке.
            this.events.add('click', this.onGeolocationButtonClick, this);
        },
        /**
         * Метод будет вызван при удалении кнопки с карты.
         * @function
         * @name GeolocationButton.onRemoveFromMap
         * @param {ymaps.Map} map Карта с которой удаляется кнопка.
         */
        onRemoveFromMap: function () {
            this.events.remove('click', this.onGeolocationButtonClick, this);
            this.hint = null;
            ymaps.option.presetStorage.remove('geolocation#icon');

            GeolocationButton.superclass.onRemoveFromMap.apply(this, arguments);
        },
        /**
         * Обработчик клика на кнопке.
         * @function
         * @private
         * @name GeolocationButton.onGeolocationButtonClick
         * @param {ymaps.Event} e Объект события.
         */
        onGeolocationButtonClick: function (e) {
            //...
        },
        //...
    });

    //...

    var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
                center: [55.755768, 37.617671],
                zoom: 10,
                behaviors: ["default", "scrollZoom"]
            }),
            myButton = new GeolocationButton({
                data: {
                    image: baseImageURL + 'wifi.png',
                    title: 'Определить местоположение'
                },
                options: {
                    // Режим получения наиболее точных данных.
                    enableHighAccuracy: true
                }
            });

    myMap.controls.add(myButton, {top: 5, left: 5});
}

ymaps.ready(init);
```

Comment: а когда он должен происходить?

Comment: Сразу после загрузки всего контента, то есть карты

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте после этой строки (50 в песочнице)

```
this.events.add('click', this.onGeolocationButtonClick, this);
```

такой код

```
this.onGeolocationButtonClick.call(this);
```

Таким образом, вызов функции нажатия на кнопку произойдет сразу при создании карты.

Comment: Огромное Вам спасибо! Вот же я недалекий человек, я добавлял именно туда такой код, но называл кнопку просто Button, не знаю с чего я решил что она так называется. в общем спасибо вам!